# Convergence of weighted series of square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a fixed non-negative sequence. 
Assume that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^q a_n$$ converges for a $q$ that we can choose as large as needed.

Fix $p\ge 1$. Is it possible to choose $q$ in the condition above (large in relation to $p$) in such a way that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^p\sqrt{a_n}$$
converges as well?

Comment: If the first series converges, we get that $a_n<1/n^q$ for large $n$, so $\sqrt{a_n}<1/n^{q/2}$. Thus if $p<q/2-1$, then $n^p\sqrt{a_n}<n^p/n^{q/2}=1/n^{1+\varepsilon}$ for $\varepsilon>0$, so the second series converges.

Comment: The same conclusion also follows by Cauchy-Schwarz: the latter series converges for $p$ provided the former converges for some $q>2p+1$

Comment: @PietroMajer can you explain how do you apply C-S? This would be very helpful.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^p \sqrt{a_n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{p-q/2}n^{q/2} \sqrt{a_n}\le \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{2p-q} } \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{q}  {a_n}}$